# create and read a .txt File on heroku with python app

Tags: python, heroku, readfile, robots.txt

i created Line-bot app using heroku as host, which can create, read, and append into a txt_files on heroku by sending a command from Line account,

so i tried to sent message to my Line-bot with command like this:

```
username = "user_name"
password = "pass_word"
```

i sent that text to my Line-bot and it saves my username and password into a txt_file(of course it check if there was no txt_file for save those data it will create txt_file automatically) on heroku, and by another command which can read the text which my Line-bot saved last time, my Line-bot sent me message and it shows:

```
username is user_name
password is pass_word
```

however after a few hours when i need my username and password/read back my data, by sending the same command, the data is gone and becomes like this

```
username is //empty 
password is //empty
```

what should i do for this problem?

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a free-level heroku account? If so, heroku does not allow permanent (long-term) file storage. As long as the dyno is shut down, any changes will be reverted.

An alternative is to use an external server as a database, but those may suffer from slower connection.

[This](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) article tells you more about heroku.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If you could summarize the relevant parts of the article, that would be preferable.  Links die, and parsing the contents of those links is a little harder than you providing value by editing/summarizing